# Draw a horizontal line on a graph where `method="loess"` has the maximum point

Tags: r, ggplot2

df

```
Date     Score  Team
1/1/2011   3    A
1/2/2011   5    A
1/3/2011   15   A
1/4/2011   39   B
1/5/2011   23   B
1/6/2011  100   B
1/7/2011   4    C
1/8/2011  25    C
1/9/2011   30   C

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Score, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T, size=1) + facet_wrap(~Team)
```

I like to be able to draw a horizontal line where method="loess" hits the maximum. Has anyone here any input on how I would accomplish that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build the plot with `ggplot_build()`, then extract the data:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Date, Score, group=1)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T, size=1)

pp <- ggplot_build(p)
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = max(pp$data[[2]]$y), col="red")
p
```

[image]

---

The results of `ggplot_build` is a list. The second element `data` is what you are looking for:

```
str(pp$data)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   9 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ x    : int [1:9] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  ..$ y    : num [1:9] 3 5 15 39 23 100 4 25 30
  ..$ group: int [1:9] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ PANEL: int [1:9] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ :'data.frame':   9 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ x    : int [1:9] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  ..$ y    : num [1:9] 1.29 8.67 19.64 24.54 53.86 ...
  ..$ ymin : num [1:9] -103.1 -60.2 -57.3 -52.4 -23 ...
  ..$ ymax : num [1:9] 105.7 77.6 96.5 101.4 130.8 ...
  ..$ se   : num [1:9] 34.8 23 25.6 25.6 25.6 ...
  ..$ group: int [1:9] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ PANEL: int [1:9] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Note that this object is a list with a data frame corresponding to each geom. In my solution I simply extract the maximum `y` and plot a `hline` through it.

---

This works for multiple facets too, but you have to do a bit more work to extract the data:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Date, Score, group=1)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T, size=1) + facet_wrap(~Team)

pp <- ggplot_build(p)

library(plyr)
hdat <- ddply(pp$data[[2]], .(PANEL), summarize, hline=max(y))
hdat$Team <- unique(df$Team)[as.numeric(hdat$PANEL)]

p <- p + geom_hline(data=hdat, aes(yintercept = hline), col="red")
p
```

[image]

Comment: I apoligize for not including all the info in the first post. Your solution works for a single graph. How would you address this if you were to use facet_wrap(~Team)?

Comment: @user1471980 Please don't do this again. But I have edited my answer.

Comment: strangely this works for some Teams and not the others. I see that it works perfectly for some Teams, and I see that some teams it is not correctly drawing the hline and some teams dont even have the hline, any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: @user1471980 Strange as it may seem, you may have to actually do _some_ of your own work yourself. Unless you're offering to pay us...? Seriously, though, how could we _possibly_ know what else is wrong when you haven't even put in the minimal effort required to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @joran, you are right. But this is great. I can definetely work with and figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Andrie I'd generally advise against using the output of `ggplot_build` unless there's no other way to get the data - here I think you'd be better off fitting the individual loess models and then extracting the maxima.